# How does scaleType and wrap_content determine ImageView width and height?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-xml, scaletype

I'm trying to understand how **layout_width/height** when sets to "wrap_content", "goes" together with **scaleType**?
AFAIK, **scaleType** (let's say *'center_fit'*) responsible of scaling up or down image size, but when width or height is set to *wrap_content*, isn't it means that the width & height of the *ImageView* will be calculated from the image (drawable) size?  So why in this situation, the drawable will be scaled at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scaleType defines how you want your image to appear in the case that the width and height isn't match / appropriate e.g. fitCenter makes it centered and fit, while fitXY stretches it if it has spaces.

Comment: thanks but you didn't refer at all to the **ImageView** dimensions. What will happen when ImageView width & height (or only one of them) is set to **wrap_content**? To which dimensions size the Image (Drawable) will be scaled?

Comment: It depends on the scaleType, if for example you chose fitXY, it will wrap its content until the image height or width is over and stretch the image. If you chose centerCrop it will check the aspect ratio of the screen compared to image, if it overlaps the screen, it will wrap until the cropped area only. If you chose fitCenter, it will wrap until it fits the whole image on the center (so this may produce white background if image aspect ratio isn't the same).

Comment: I think an example can help here :) if it's ok.. Let's say i have an ImageView with heights sets to 100 and width sets to 'wrap_content'. And a Image (Drawable) with size 60*70. and let's say that the scaleType one time is sets to "fitYt" and another time sets to 'centerCrop', can you please tell me what will be the ImageView size in each of the situation? I hope with numbers it will be easier for me to understand.. I will be happy to hear from you. I'm asking because i read that is such case, people told me to use 'adjustViewBounds' attribute and i can't understand why. Thanks anyway

Comment: I am not sure about fitYt since these are the only types https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType but, what adjustViewBounds true does, is it makes sure you won't have any white background as much as it can, so long as you have a fair enough aspect ratio. In your case 60*70 won't have any white background centerCrop or fitCenter. Without adjustViewBounds however, the chances of you having the white background is higher, you can experiment this with disproportionate aspect ratio e.g. super long height but small width.

Comment: ok thanks. Can you please approve that in case of 'centerCrop' that width of the ImageView will be about 85? according to 60*(100/70)?

Comment: It still depends on a lot of things, especially the density pixel of the device you are using. so we cannot jump into conclusions unless we know for sure the environment the image + imageView is running

Comment: ok thakns a lot. Hope the designer will provide a good images :)

Comment: @Mike thanks for the adjustViewBounds. Just what I was looking for.